# Moving function from functions.php to plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm probably doing something stupid.

But i have the following working code, (this a small (but working) part of the code) if i have this code in my functions.php it works fine, but when i add it in a custom plugin, it does not

```
function update_booklink_field( $post_id ) {
if( ! ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id) || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) ) {

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'prijstest', 'testvalue' ); 
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_booklink_field' );
```

This is my code in the plugin, is there something obvious i am missing? Or are there extra steps i need to take to trigger a function when it is in a plugin?

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: aaautofill
*/

  function update_booklink_field( $post_id ) {
    if( ! ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id) || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) ) {

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'prijstest', 'testvalue' ); 
    }
    }
    add_action( 'save_post', 'update_booklink_field' );






?>
```

EDIT:

What i found out so far:
if i move

> add_action( 'save_post', 'update_booklink_field');

to the functions file, then it works. 
The plugin is activated, but the save_post just doesnt run when its in my plugin file. i really have 0 clue what is causing this :/

edit 2:

Basicly the function doesnt seem to have an issue, because if i change the location of when its loaded (in the fucntion.php) it works fine.

1. Issue is the add_action save hook (probably) because
2. plugin is live/active/works (tested with var dumbs)
3. the function also works, if the add_action is in the functions.php vs when it's in the plugin file.

   4. no other plugins are live,  default twenty seventeen,  theme

Does this mean it has to do with the order in which the things are loaded? (or am i overlooking something stupid?)

Edit 3,  i found it/got it working
if i changed the save_post line to:

> add_action( 'save_post', 'update_booklink_field', 50 , 50 );

it works

Comment: What error are you getting?  How is it "not working"?

Comment: i am not getting an error, it just doesnt update the field  (it updates fine if that code is in the functions.php file though)

Comment: Are you sure you activated the plugin? What happens if you just do a test var_dump like `var_dump('testing');` outside the function? Does it show up on the front end?

Comment: yeh, the plugin is activated,  and if i add "var_dump('testing');" outside that fuction, i see "string(7) "testing"  on the front end

Comment: That's good. That said, I don't know what the problem is, but maybe the $post_id variable isn't working. Maybe try defining it `$post_id = get_the_ID();`

Comment: i tried that, but no luck (i also hardcoded the post_id as a test, update_post_meta( "717", 'prijstest', 'testvalue' ); 
but no succes with that either

Comment: What i found out so far, is if i move "add_action( 'save_post', 'update_booklink_field');"  to the functions file,  then it works.  The plugin is activated, but the save_post just doesnt run when its in my plugin file.  i really have 0 clue what is causing this :/

Comment: Try passing arguments in the action hook 
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_booklink_field', 10, 1 );

Comment: also doesnt work :/ (thank you for having a look)

Comment: got it working, had to change it to add_action( 'save_post', 'update_booklink_field', 20 , 20 ); 
the fact that it works now, does this mean it loaded in the wrong order before?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will do the trick:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: aaautofill
*/

function update_booklink_field( ) {

global $post;

if( ! ( wp_is_post_revision( $post->ID ) || wp_is_post_autosave( $post->ID ) ) ) {

 update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'prijstest', 'testvalue' ); 
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_booklink_field' );

?>
```

Comment: thank you for having a look, but afraid not,  same issue again, if i have that in my plugin, it doesnt work.  if i remove the add_action line, and add that part in my functions.php. it works fine again